# Mac and Windows Server 2008-based SSTP VPN. Does it work?

Tags: windows, linux, macos, vpn, windows-server-2008

Does anyone know how to set up a Mac with a Windows Server 2008 SSTP VPN? Is it even supported? We have said VPN installed here, and I need to know if we can have Macs as well as Linux clients working with it.

Comment: so its a client part of sstp in linux. how about server part of sstp in linux,any idea how to do it thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be possible.
Below are some sources for this information.

[wikipedia: Secure Socket Tunneling Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Socket_Tunneling_Protocol)

> SSTP is only available in Windows
>   since version Windows Vista SP1, and
>   in RouterOS. It is fully integrated
>   with the RRAS architecture in these
>   operating systems, allowing its use
>   with Winlogon or smart card
>   authentication, remote access policies
>   and the Windows VPN client.

[PPTP/L2TP problems and SSL solutions](http://vpnblog.info/pptp-l2tp-problems-ssl-solutions.html)

> SSTP is a great addition to the VPN
>   toolkit to enable users to remotely
>   and securely connect to the corporate
>   network. But there is no solution for
>   Linux, MAC OS and other OS, SSTP
>   limited only for Windows users and
>   seems it's a big problem.

The next two sources are from private VPN providers.

[VPN Gates](http://www.vpngates.com/sstpvpn/)

> If you use a computer that installed
>   Windows Vista or Windows 7,
>   Congratulates you! you can use SSTP
>   vpn on your computer. It's unfortunate
>   that other operating system do not
>   support SSTP vpn current.

[Black Logic](https://blacklogic.com/sstpvpn.php)

> SSTP Configuration instructions can be
>   found here: SSTP VPN Configuration for
>   Windows 7

Comment: Ah well. Too bad. Seems like we'll be running OpenVPN in parallel at some point.

Answer (score 1):

There IS a Mac alternative, but that unfortunately seems to have been discontinued--the developer Llamedos Software seem to have shut down last summer when their website disappeared.  It's called EasySSTP and is a .dmg file with a nice GUI and everything! A search for EasySSTP should get you to a cached version of the app at some VPN provider out there. The latest version seems to be 1.0.4 or 1.0.10, whichever is the highest.

I have had some problems finding such versions, but it does work if you can get hold of it.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Thanks for posting your answer. I've cleaned up the structure of your post a bit -- please check that I haven't messed up what you meant to say -- many apologies if so!

Answer (score 1):

I also came across this problem. Here's my finding:

1. EasySSTP (http://www.llamedos-software.com/easysstp.html)

   As @Hasse pointed out, the company is no longer supporting the app. The site takes to a blank page. However, you can still download it from PureVPN (http://support.purevpn.com/configuration-guide-for-sstp-protocol-on-mac). Note, that some VPNs also cache this file for their own. You can ask your VPN service provider.
2. sstp-client (http://sstp-client.sourceforge.net/)

   It's a command-line tool and to my experience, I tried this, hard to use. The latest version (1.0.10), as of this writing, doesn't have `.dmg` file. You have to compile yourself, which is a headache (compilation requires `libevent-dev`, `libssl-dev`, `ppp-dev`, and `zlib` packages. Or you can use Macports to compile it, see https://www.macports.org/). However, version 1.0.9 does have `.dmg` file, compiled by Macports.

   The Network Manager Plugin (part of sstp-client project), is not for Mac. They are plugin for Debian / Ubuntu distro to sit on top of their own Network Manager.
3. iSSTP (http://www.axot.org/2015/03/03/isstp-a-sstp-client-for-mac-osx/)

   Seems promising, I have never tried it. It's based on sstp-client project. There is also another guide here: https://adtelly.tv/sstp-vpn-on-mac-os-x/
4. Softether VPN (https://www.softether.org/5-download)

   Softether writes SSTP VPN client for Mac OSX, however, the download page encourage you to NOT use it as it's still experimental.
5. PureVPN (http://download.cnet.com/PureVPN/3000-2092_4-76171308.html)

   PureVPN has its own VPN client which support SSTP. I suspect, you can use its client to connect to another SSTP server as well. I have never tried it. Free to try, $10 to buy.

Part of the reasons I didn't try EasySSTP, iSSTP and Softether is because they are not hosted in a public site (Sourceforge, download.com or app store) so, to me, they have less credibility. However, I have read in forums, different people have tried them and they work. Try at your own risk.

And while we are on the subject, there is currently a feedback open at Windows Azure to push for creation of SSTP VPN client for Mac. If you would vote on it, that'd be great! We can soon have SSTP VPN client for Mac.

http://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-azure-networking/suggestions/4233968-either-add-point-to-site-sstp-vpn-clients-for-mac

Answer (score 0):

There are two client implementations available for Linux: [sstoper](http://www.hsc.fr/ressources/outils/sstoper/index.html.en) and [sstp-client](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sstp-client).

I am trying to use the first one at the moment. The VPN I am trying to connect to uses EAP with certificates, but pppd does not seem to support it. I am hoping that the EAP_TLS patch for pppd might help but no luck so far.